# Entity Framework - DRY Queries

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a Entity Framework Domain model (using code first) with a context that includes Customers, and each Customer can have multiple Addresses with a 'calendar range' of dates on each address.  I can write a query such as:

```
var query = from c in context.Customers
where c.CustomerId == 1
select c
Customer cust = query.Single();
```

The resulting customer is the one I selected via my Where clause.  No problem.  Now I also want to get their mailing address for a view, so I'd do:

```
var query = from c in context.Customers
where c.CustomerId == 1
select new 
{
    FirstName = c.FirstName,
    Address = c.Addresses.Where(a => a.AddressStartDate > DateTime.Now && 
        a.AddressEndDate < DateTime.Now)
}
var data = query.Single();
Address MailingAddress = data.Address;
```

Again, no problem, I get customer information and the current mailing address and the query executes in SQL.

Now I want to factor out the query that does the finding of the mailing address.  I don't want to repeat it in every call that needs to get a mailing address.  Ideally I'd like to add it to my domain object Customer so that the logic for finding mailing address is a part of my Customer object.

I want to place a method like this in my Customer object:

```
public partial class Customer 
{
    public Address MailingAddress
    {
        get
        {
           return (from a in this.Addresses.AsQueryable()
               where a.AddressStartDate > DateTime.Now && 
                   a.AddressEndDate < DateTime.Now
               select a).Single()
        }
    }
}
```

Now that I have the property in my Domain Model, I want to run a query:

```
var query = from c in context.Customers
    where customerId == 1
    select new 
    {
        FirstName = c.FirstName,
        Address = c.MailingAddress
    }
```

Unfortunately this does not work with the error **'Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'**  I understand the error, and why I can't do it that way.  I also know that my method would actually work if I retrieved the Customer first and then called the MailingAddress property after I had an instance of a Customer, but this doubles the database calls.

How can I stay DRY using Entity Framework?  I need to centralize the code for the 'get mailing address' requirement while also making sure I execute the logic for 'get mailing address' in SQL and in one db operation?

Comment: No takers?  So far with my experience in Domain Driven Design, this is a significant problem to solve with an Entity Framework based implementation.  I found some hints that linqkit might facilitate, will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

The general way I've gone about solving this is to have a navigation property to the address so the class would look like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MailingAddressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MailingAddressId")]
    public virtual Address MailingAddress { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can go:

```
var customer = context.Customer.Include("MailingAddress").FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id = 1);
```

Comment: I'll agree that a navigation property would be the way to go in this particular case, but it doesn't answer the question for other cases where it isn't appropriate.  Let's say the data model is more complex (which in reality it is, I contrived this situation to simplify).  In the complex scenario, the user has multiple mailing addresses and they have start/end dates so that the proper mailing address is 'scheduled'. Now the navigation property is no longer possible because the foreign key would not be possible. I need to filter on date and find the proper address in that case.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify the complexity and the need for factoring out the business logic that implements 'Find the mailing address' to more closely align with the real world scenario.